# Change the url parameter 'search_api_views_fulltext' used in views exposed filter

Tags: views, search

Im trying to modify the url parameter 'search_api_views_fulltext' so that it becomes nicer to read.

i would like something like "s" or "search"

Im using search_api + search_api_db + facet_api modules, with views.

Ive been looking every where but couldn't find any way to do this

Maybe someone among you guys could have an idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a settings "Filter identifier" under More fieldset when you expose a field.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, didn't know you could do that

Comment: Thanks Sumit  ... and you know what ? I found it myself 2 minutes ago (didnt check your answers yet) ... I feel kinda silly ... This was just in front of my eyes ...  thank you anyway !